# How can Zapier create Trello Cards for Closed Won Salesforce Opportunities when the Opportunity is not new?

Tags: salesforce, trello, zapier

Maybe this just isn't possible with the available Salesforce actions in Zapier, but I thought I'd ask.

You can monitor for a new opportunity, but I only want to create cards for opportunities which are closed won. So if a new opportunity is created on Monday and on Friday it is Closed Won, Zapier will never get notified when it is updated.

Seems like a very common use case, I figure someone has figured this out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took this to Zapier Support and they said....

> So the tricky thing here is the "New Opportunity" trigger will only
>   happen when the Zap sees the record for the first time. Even if it's
>   updated later, the Zap will not re-trigger on it.
>
> We do have a way to trigger on updated Salesforce records, but it
>   would require using their Workflow Rules and Outbound Messaging
>   option. Then on the Zapier side, you'd use the Salesforce "New
>   Outbound Message" trigger.
>
> You basically set a workflow rule + outbound message in Salesforce.
>   And so all your triggering conditions (like which object/field) are on
>   the Salesforce side.
>
> First you'd set up the Outbound Message, specifying the object and
>   fields you want to send, and the Zap url:
>   https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_managing_outbound_messages.htm
>
> Then you'd set up the Workflow Rule, specifying the conditions where
>   the rule should trigger, and which actions to trigger (the outbound
>   message action that you just made):
>   https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=customize_wf.htm
>
> The one caveat here is that workflow rules are only available on some
>   editions of Salesforce. So you may have to check and see if your
>   edition supports it.
>
> Please let me know if you have any questions about that -- happy to
>   help!

And that worked so yay Zapier for helping me with Salesforce!